# List comprehension including elements of different sizes

Tags: python

I have the following `for/if-elif-else` loop which extracts department information from tuples `t` in a list, based on the size of `t[0]`:

```
for t in filt:
    if len(t[0]) == 1:
        pass
    elif len(t[0]) == 2:
        if 'organization' in t[0][0]['affiliation']:
            depA = t[0][0]['affiliation']['organization']
        else: depA = 'Not Available'

        if 'organization' in t[0][1]['affiliation']:
            depB = t[0][1]['affiliation']['organization']
        else: depB = 'Not Available'

        depC = 'None'


    else:
        if 'organization' in t[0][0]['affiliation']:
            depA = t[0][0]['affiliation']['organization']
        else: depA = 'Not Available'

        if 'organization' in t[0][1]['affiliation']:
            depB = t[0][1]['affiliation']['organization']
        else: depB = 'Not Available'

        if 'organization' in t[0][2]['affiliation']:
            depC = t[0][1]['affiliation']['organization']
        else: depC = 'Not Available'
```

Is there a way to do things like this in a single line even though the sizes of `t[0]` may be different. The reason I ask is that I may be incorrectly assuming that there are a maximum of 3 departments in `t[0]` when there in fact may be more and I'd like to save lines of code if possible.

In essence what I'd really like is something like having a list of a sensible number of the maximum possible departments based on my data ie 6 and then have something like

```
for t in filt:
    depA = [t[0][0]['affiliation']['organization'] if 'organization' in t[0][0]['affiliation'] else 'Not Available']
```

which is fine because `t[0]` is always of size at least 1. But here's where it gets tricky and the line of code below won't make pythonic sense:

```
depB = [t[0][1]['affiliation']['organization'] if t[0][1] exists AND 'organization' in t[0][1]['organization'] else 'Not Available']
```

and so forth...

If I haven't worded the question title right, please change as required! Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually showed some of that source data, and not only the code that acts upon it.

Comment: Shall fetch it for you now

Comment: The only change I'd make to that code is to remove the `if len(t[0]) == 1: pass` and change the `else:` to `elif len(t[0]) != 1:...`. I wouldn't want to put such a long expression into one line.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to avoid is having a ridiculous amount of lines of code for if statements considering the size of `t[0]` up to 6

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the following line of code will work, checking the index against the size of the list in question and using if else in the list comprehension:

```
depB = [t[0][1]['affiliation']['organization'] if 2<=len(t[0]) and 'organization' in t[0][1]['affiliation'] else 'Not Available' for t in filt]
```